# google map multi marker

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project. I use google map and php in the project. When a query run I get latlong value from database. I defined limit 1 in the query. Later I show the position latlong value with a marker on the map. I want to show limit 5 with multi marker. How can I show all markers on the map?  My query and query result on the below. The variable geom is a condition and my google map script some part on the below.

```
Query:
SELECT lat, lng from mytable where $geom limit 5; 

Php code:
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $lat=$row['lat'];
 $lng=$row['lng'];
 }

Google Map js:
 var myLatLng = {lat:<?php echo $lat;?>, lng:<?php echo $lng;?>};
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 19,
      center: myLatLng
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
```

Comment: Only make one map, multiple markers.

Comment: yes.  I want to show all latlong values on the markers.

Comment: Well, right now your code makes a new map for every marker.

Comment: What does your current code do?

Answer (score 1):

Only create the map once.  Add all the markers to that map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lng = $row['lng'];

    var myLatLng = {lat:<?php echo $lat;?>, lng:<?php echo $lng;?>};
    bounds.extend(myLatLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
map.fitBounds(bounds); // center and zoom the map to show all the markers
```

Comment: Your solution is good. Already I wanted to do as your written. But here problem is I can't run js code in while loop. Because I also get another column with query and I print to html code. I displayed my some part of code. Shortly I explain. I get row['lat'] and row['lng'] with while. İt is two array. I want to print all array element to js code. As:var myLatLng={lat:<?php row['lat'] >?, lng:<?php row['lng']>?} I hope I could have explained.